# Docusign: Removing Signer completes envelope

Tags: docusignapi

We have a docusign document that was sent to a customer. Customer couldn't access it, so our customer service sent the document via docusign to him again. So now we have 2 docusign documents for the customer. I wanted to cancel one of them, but I didn't want the customer to be notified because they see the document being voided and they get confused. So I removed the customer from the envelope through REST API and I was going to void the envelope but after I removed the customer from the document, docusign changed envelope's status to complete. I also had Carbon Copy recipients in the envelope.

Any idea how to work around this? Voiding an envelope without sending a notification to the customer? And why is docusign changing the envelope's status to complete?

Answer (score 2):

- This sounds like remote signing, and therefore DocuSign will be sending out various emails to recipients depending on the action. IF the customer has a DocuSign account there are options that user can set on which email notifications to receive, but for the most part we can assume they do not. If you void the envelope, they will receive a notification.
- When you removed the recipient from the envelope the workflow continued forward (to the CC recipient). As all explicit and required actions by the roles in this transaction are completed, the envelope will transition into a completed state.

Comment: Reminder: when you void an envelope you can include a void reason which will appear in the email that is sent out. This can help add clarity.